# Struggling with 2d Tree Implementation of Nearest Neighbor Search

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am having difficulty implementing the 2d Tree data structure. I'm going to outline what I have done here in the hopes that someone will be able to tell me what's going wrong.

Many thanks to all of you for your time.

Here is the assignment: https://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/kdtree/specification.php

Here is the method spec for *Nearest-neighbor search*: To find a closest point to a given query point, start at the root and recursively search in both subtrees using the following pruning rule: if the closest point discovered so far is closer than the distance between the query point and the rectangle corresponding to a node, there is no need to explore that node (or its subtrees). That is, search a node only only if it might contain a point that is closer than the best one found so far. The effectiveness of the pruning rule depends on quickly finding a nearby point. To do this, organize the recursive method so that when there are two possible subtrees to go down, you always choose the subtree that is on the same side of the splitting line as the query point as the first subtree to explore—the closest point found while exploring the first subtree may enable pruning of the second subtree.

Here is what I've done.

1. Set a champion equal to root.
2. Take left and right nodes of champion.
3. If both are non-null, calculate three things - a. distance from current champion to point p (championDistance), b. distance from point p to left rectangle (leftRectDistance), c. distance from p to right rectangle (rightRectDistance). Note: both of these last two calculations employ the distanceSquaredTo(Point2D p) method in the RectHV class.
4. Compute which one is smaller - this is the side I will search first. Say, for the sake of argument, it is the left node.
5. For this left node - check whether or not this node's point is closer than championDistance. If so, then set champion to this node and start over from (2)

After this recursion in (5) is done, check whether or not right node's  rightRectDistance is less than the post-recursion champion's node's point's distance to p. If so, then find the "champion" for the right node and start over from (2). Then, compare the left champion point with the right champion point and choose the nearer one.

Re: step (3) - if only one node is non-null, then repeat (5) but only for the one node available.

6. After all this is done, the champion should be pointing to the node with the point closest to p.

```
    // a nearest neighbor in the set to point p; null if the set is empty
    public Point2D nearest(Point2D p) {
        if (p == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return nearest(root, p, root.point.distanceSquaredTo(p));
    }

    private Point2D nearest(Node champNode, Point2D queryPoint, double champDistance) {
        if (champNode.lb == null && champNode.rt == null) return champNode.point;

        Point2D champPoint = champNode.point;
        if (champNode.lb != null && champNode.rt != null) {

            // to determine which side to examine first
            double leftRectDistance = champNode.lb.rect.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint);
            double rightRectDistance = champNode.rt.rect.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint);

            // exploring left side first
            if (leftRectDistance < rightRectDistance) {
                double potentialDistance = champNode.lb.point.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint);
                // update champ point
                if (potentialDistance < champDistance) {
                    champPoint = nearest(champNode.lb, queryPoint, potentialDistance);

                    // search right side if rightRectDistance < distance to the current champion.
                    if (rightRectDistance < champPoint.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint)) {
                        Point2D potentialNewChampPoint = nearest(champNode.rt, queryPoint,
                                                                 champDistance);

                        // compare two "champ" points
                        if (potentialNewChampPoint.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint) < champPoint
                                .distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint)) {
                            champPoint = potentialNewChampPoint;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // exploring right side first
            else {
                double potentialDistance = champNode.rt.point.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint);
                // update champ point
                if (potentialDistance < champDistance) {
                    champPoint = nearest(champNode.rt, queryPoint, potentialDistance);

                    // search left side if leftRectDistance < distance to the current champion.
                    if (leftRectDistance < champPoint.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint)) {
                        Point2D potentialNewChampPoint = nearest(champNode.lb, queryPoint,
                                                                 champDistance);

                        // compare two "champ" points
                        if (potentialNewChampPoint.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint) < champPoint
                                .distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint)) {
                            champPoint = potentialNewChampPoint;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (champNode.lb != null && champNode.rt == null) {
            double leftRectDistance = champNode.lb.rect.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint);
            if (leftRectDistance < champPoint.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint)) {
                double potentialDistance = champNode.lb.point.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint);
                Point2D potentialNewChampPoint = nearest(champNode.lb, queryPoint,
                                                         potentialDistance);
                if (potentialNewChampPoint.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint) < champPoint
                        .distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint)) {
                    champPoint = potentialNewChampPoint;
                }
            }
        }
        if (champNode.rt != null && champNode.lb == null) {
            double rightRectDistance = champNode.rt.rect.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint);
            if (rightRectDistance < champPoint.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint)) {
                double potentialDistance = champNode.rt.point.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint);
                Point2D potentialNewChampPoint = nearest(champNode.rt, queryPoint,
                                                         potentialDistance);
                if (potentialNewChampPoint.distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint) < champPoint
                        .distanceSquaredTo(queryPoint)) {
                    champPoint = potentialNewChampPoint;
                }
            }
        }
        return champPoint;
    }
```

Thank you very much!